# Не могу решить задачу "отсортировать вводимые значения в зависимости от типа между массивами int и String" с помощью try-catch

Tags: java, массивы, исключения, for, try-catch

написать программу которая будет сотритровать вводимые значения пользователем в массивы, в зависимости от их типа и выводить их в консоль по окончании заполнения. Для задачи условимся что пользователь вводит только int и String значения.
Если пользователь введет значение типа "GTR200k", то оно обрабатывается в String массив, т.е. вычленять int из строки не нужно.

Отдельно посоветовали делать через try-catch, потому что если чередовать nextLine(); и nextInt();, в массив будут заноситься значения переноса строки, вместо реальных значений.
Предположил что можно сделать только через nextLine(); а если там будет чистый int, ловить его NumberFormatException и перезаписывать его в интовый массив.

У меня проблема с тем как сделать структуру из циклов for, здесь она неверная, по факту сканнер дает ввести 8 строк вместо 4. И не знаю, правильно ли использовал try-catch (в первый раз его юзал).

Подскажите, как исправить структуру кода, буду благодарен!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution{
    public static int[] intArray = new int[2];
    public static String[] StringArray = new String[2];
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s = null;
        int number;
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length+ StringArray.length; i++) {
        try {
            s = sc.nextLine();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            number = Integer.parseInt(s);
            for (int k = 0; k < intArray.length; k++) {
                intArray[k] = number;
            }
        }
        finally{
            s = sc.nextLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < StringArray.length; j++) {
                StringArray[j] = s;
            }
        }}
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(StringArray));
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Catch(Исключение){Обработка}`
ловит указанное исключение в try{вот здесь} и обрабатывает его в {Обработке} .Если ошибки нет, то catch не срабатывает.
Тебе скорее всего советовали преобразовывать в integer "s" сразу после считывания nextLine, и если возникает ошибка то в {Обработке} сразу отправлять в массив строк.

```
        int number, countInt = 0 ,countString = 0; // счетчики для массивов
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length+ StringArray.length; i++) {
            try {
                s = sc.nextLine();
                number = Integer.parseInt(s);
                intArray[countInt++] = number; // если не выкинуло ошибку то доходит сюда
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                StringArray[countString++] = s; //если выкинуло то идет сюда
                }
            }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(StringArray));
    } 

Единственное, раз у тебя массив ограничен двумя значением то при попытке считывания 3 выкинет ошибку.
```

Comment: Сейчас переделал. Правильно ли вас понял?  https://pastenow.ru/J29U9

Comment: Если честно не очень понял про блок finally. Пишут что в нем прописывается сценарий что делать дальше, если ошибка преодолена. Я написал по сути дубль того что было в try: понял так, что  если в finally строка String преобразуется в int, то значит это уже чистый инт, и ее нужно добавить в массив интов

Comment: Метод finally выполняется при любом (кроме некоторых маленьких исключений) исходе, можешь почитать https://habr.com/ru/company/golovachcourses/blog/223821/ тут исчерпывающе информации о try-catch-finally.Конкретно тебе finally не нужен в твоей ситуации.

Comment: Если помогло отметь, как решение.

Comment: Ого, спасибо!! Знали бы вы сколько времени я убил на эту задачу. 3 дня!!!